# Firestore 'get' query for all documents in a collection returns no documents

Tags: firebase, react-native, collections, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have this code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('items').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(snapshot._docs));
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        Alert.alert(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      Alert.alert('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

The `Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(snapshot._docs))` returns an empty array - so it is not finding any documents. There is one document in this collection:

[image]

Is it because I am using an email address for the document id?

**UPDATE**

An image to show the rest of my database structure:

[image]

I am trying to search through document fields under `PxlmyvjklhTOADngsSQg` under `userItems` (and other objects that would go there).

**UPDATE**

This is essentially what I am trying to do, only in theory I would want to use a wildcard for `.doc(this.state.user.email)`:

`firebase.firestore().collection('items').doc(**wildcard**).collection('userItems').where("barcode", "==", this.state.text)`

But I know that isn't possible with `firebase`, so I am trying to get all of the `items` and then parse through them after a successful retrieval.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for having email as document ID but maybe you can look into this document you create as I find it your document ID is in italic which is different from normal scenario.

Comment: Does that document contain any fields? You can also try adding more docs

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes so the structure is `collection(items)->document(eamon.white7@gmail.com)->collection(userItems)->documents` and I am trying to search through the fields in the `documents` objects (children of `userItems`). I will update my question with a picture.

Comment: In practice, there would be more than one document under `items` where `eamon.white7@...` is - and I need to search through all of the documents for all of the `userItem` collections for each document under `items` (ex. document with id: `eamon.white7@gmail.com`).

Comment: I'm guessing maybe the problem..and reason for italics..is I'm not allowed to bulk retrieve `document`s that each lead to their own `collection`?

Comment: @AngusTay maybe it is in italics because it holds a collection?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you are reaching into the snapshot object using private properties:

```
snapshot._docs
```

That's not the right way to do it.  The snapshot you get back from a query is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object, and you should use the API docs to understand how to deal with it.  If you want an array of docs from the snapshot, use its [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property.

Second, your screenshot is actually showing that there are no documents int the items collection.  Notice that the document identified by the email address is in italics.  That means it's not actually a document - it's just a "phantom" document that you're using to organize a subcollection underneath it called `userItems`.

When you query a collection, you only get documents that are immediately in that collection, and none of their documents subcollections.  Queries are said to be "shallow" in this way.  Try creating an actual document with fields immediately in `items`, then query the collection.

Comment: thank u, do you have a suggestion for how to structure my database?